# Extending an ArrayList of Lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Why is it not possible to do something like this?

```
RowList<List<Value>> extends ArrayList<List<Value>>
```

Also, how is it possible to do this?

```
RowList<Value> extends ArrayList<List<Value>>
```

I'm trying to implement a `List` to be used in a `database`, and want to extend `ArrayList` so I'm able to check that the `.add(),.set()` etc. methods do not violate the requirements of the `Database` (not adding two rows with the same keys etc). I realise that it's probably not the best way to implement a `database`, but it's an assignment for college that required us to do it this way.

EDIT: Using the 2nd option (that compiles), how is it possible to access the Values within the Lists that the RowList class holds?

Comment: What about `RowList<T> extends ArrayList<List<T>>`?

Comment: @Supericy That works fine, yeah, but isn't what I want to do.

Comment: Why in the first place would you want to extend `ArrayList`? Looks like a code smell.

Comment: By the way, if you don't want repeated items in the `Collection`, use a [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Issue is following code doesn't work:import java.util.List;

class A<D>{
    
}


class C<List<T>> extends A<List<T>>{
    
} but this code works: import java.util.List;

class A<D>{
    
}


class C<T> extends A<List<T>>{
    
}

Comment: @loki in your `C` class you haven't defined what's `T`, thus getting your error. Still, it's not a valid reason to extend `ArrayList`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza As I said, it's part of an assignment. I agree that a Set is more suitable, but that's not where my issue is here.

Comment: I get your point on ArrayList, probably a better deisgn can help. COming to class C, when i say class C<List<T>> then doesn't it mean that C is of list type where list contains elements of type T?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following two lines are identical (to the compiler), this is true even if you have a class called `Value` as the named parameter will mask the class type

```
class RowList<Value> extends ArrayList<List<Value>>

class RowList<T> extends ArrayList<List<T>>
```

The reason for this is because value inside the first `<>` is a named type parameter. So when you attempt to do something like

```
class RowList<List<Value>> extends ArrayList<List<Value>>
```

You have attempted to create a named type paramter `List<Value>` which (in Java) is an invalid identifier, but instead you will get an error something like `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

I think instead you are really trying to write

```
public class RowList extends ArrayList<Value> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(Value e) {
        // TODO Custom code to check and what not
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

Where `Value` is a custom object in your codebase. Then elsewhere in your code you can do:

```
RowList rl = new RowList();
rl.add(new Value(...));
Value v = rl.get(i);
```

**EDIT:**

The previous example assumes that the `Value` class is an entry row of data. If instead it is a single item of data, and the row is represented by a `List` then it would be more like the following:

```
public class RowList extends ArrayList<List<Value>> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(List<Value> e) {
        // TODO Custom code to check and what not
        return super.add(e);
    }
}

RowList rl = new RowList();
List<Value> row = new ArrayList<Value>();
row.add(new Value(...));
rl.add(row);
List<Value> rowGet = rl.get(i);
```

Comment: Yeah, Value is an object in my code. Using the class RowList extends ArrayList<List<Value>> declaration, how do I access the values within RowList?